# How can I add a star rating with Disqus?

Tags: jquery, disqus

I have a website that already implements Disqus and would also like a star rating system.  I have already found ways of doing a separate star system, however, I would like to integrate it with the Disqus comments, either by using something that Disqus already offers or by allowing the star rating once the user is logged in to Disqus using jQuery.

Does Disqus have something like this, or do I have to make it myself?

And, if I do make it myself, how can I check if the user is logged in to Disqus to allow the star rating?

Comment: you should check discus api

Answer (score 3):

There is no real good solution here because you can't insert any code into the Disqus embed.

Technically the only way would be to recreate the Disqus embed using the API with your own enhancements, but you're limited to 1000 API calls/hour for free accounts so it would have to be a fairly low-volume site. If you do want to put that together, check out the [API documentation](http://disqus.com/api/docs/) as well as some [examples](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes)

Specifically for authenticating, here are some resources that can help get you started:

Documentation: http://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/

Examples: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/python/oauth and https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/tree/master/php/oauth